# toggle div along side one another with css and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to toggle a div along side another when an image has been clicked. As it toggles open it should push the div next to it to the left. When toggled closed the div along side it moves back to its position...What it does now is toggle on top of the div next to it. This is my code.

```
   img{
   margin-left:0px;
  }

  #info {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -310px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 308px;
    background-color: #F4F4EE;
   }

   #container {
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }
```

The jQuery...

```
     $(document).ready( function(){
  hideInfo();
     });

    function hideInfo(){
       $( '#container > div' ).hide();

      $('#container a').click(function(){
      $(this).next().animate({
               width: "toggle",
               height: "toggle"}, 
           {duration: 700, 
            specialEasing: {width: "linear"},
         });
       });
    }
```

The Html

```
        <body>
        <div id="container">
   <a href="#"><img src="button.jpg"/></a> /*image must be clicked to toggle the div */
  <div id="info" class="panel">
        Information in div 1
   </div>
           <a href="#"><img src="button2.jpg"/></a               
            <div id="info"  class="panel">
                 information in the second div
         </div>
     <div>
   </body>
```

Comment: If you appreciate my answer, don't forget to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points! If a better answer comes along later, you can switch to that one. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

Easy stuff! Here's an example. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/esUZUjom/4/edit)

The important part ist just the css `float` and `width` on the toggled element.

sample markup:

```
<img id="click" src="http://th01.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2011/285/3/0/feel_like_a_sir_by_rober_raik-d4clwcf.png">
<div id="add">Toggled content in here.</div>
<div>Some content in here.</div>
```

the css:

```
#add {
  display: none;
  float: left; /* change to right if needed */
  width: 20%;
}
```

JavaScript (just for toggling the extra element):

```
var img = document.getElementById('click');
var add = document.getElementById('add');

img.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var display = add.style.display;
  add.style.display = (add.style.display == 'none' || !add.style.display) ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

---

---

Now, onto the pro stuff. Ditch the javascript! 
[Pure html/css solution live demo here. (click).](http://jsbin.com/esUZUjom/9/edit)

The trick here is to take advantage of being able to
1. check checkboxes via their label
2. style checkboxes that are checked with :checked
3. select elements that are a sibling of what is `:checked` with `~`

Wrap the image in the label for the checkbox - thus checking the checkbox when clicking the image. Hide the checkbox with `display: none`. Style/Animate the toggled element. Win.

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">
  <img src="http://th01.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2011/285/3/0/feel_like_a_sir_by_rober_raik-d4clwcf.png">
</label>
<div class="add">Toggled content in here.</div>
<div>Some content in here.</div>
```

and the magic css:

```
.add {
  float: left; /* change to right if needed */
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .add {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
}
```